# Generate matrix of unique user-item cross-product combinations

Tags: r, matrix, unique, combinations, cross-product

I am trying to create a cross-product matrix of unique users in R. I searched for it on SO but could not find what I was looking for. Any help is appreciated.
I have a large dataframe (over a million) and a sample is shown:

```
df <- data.frame(Products=c('Product a', 'Product b', 'Product a', 
                            'Product c', 'Product b', 'Product c'),
                 Users=c('user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user1', 
                         'user2','user3'))
```

Output of df is:

```
   Products Users
1 Product a user1
2 Product b user1
3 Product a user2
4 Product c user1
5 Product b user2
6 Product c user3
```

I would like to see two matrices:
The first one will show the number of unique users that had either products(OR) - so the output will be something like:

```
            Product a   Product b   Product c
Product a                 2            3
Product b     2                        3
Product c     3           3
```

The second matrix will be the number of unique users that had both products(AND):

```
            Product a   Product b   Product c
Product a                 2            1
Product b     2                        1
Product c     1           1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Here is more clarity: Product a is used by User1 and User2. Product b is used by User1 and User2 and Product c is used by User1 and User3. So in the first matrix, Product a and Product b will be 2 since there are 2 unique users. Similarly, Product a and Product c will be 3. Where as in the second matrix, they would be 2 and 1 since I want the intersection.
Thanks

Comment: Does the numbers in the expected output represent the values in the example showed?  For the second case, may be `tbl <- table(merge(df, df, by.x='Users', by.y='Users')[-1]);
diag(tbl) <- 0`

Comment: @akrun I agree with you...the sample df output does not appear to agree with the desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The first case is not clear.  I am getting the expected output for the second one

Comment: Or the second output can be `tcrossprod(table(df))*!diag(3)`

Comment: @akrun They should. Here is more clarity: Product a is used by User1 and User2. Product b is used by User1 and User2 and Product c is used by User1 and User3. So in the first matrix, prod a and prod b  will be 2 since there are 2 unique users. Similarly, prod a and prod c will be 3. Where as in the second matrix, they would be 2 and 1. Thankx

Comment: It's unfortunate you called them 'Product ...' instead of 'Item ...', since the term *'product'* also arises in cross-product. Suggest renaming to *'unique user-item cross-product combinations'*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
lst <- split(df$Users, df$Products)
ln <- length(lst)
m1 <-  matrix(0, ln,ln, dimnames=list(names(lst), names(lst)))
m1[lower.tri(m1, diag=FALSE)] <- combn(seq_along(lst), 2, 
               FUN= function(x) length(unique(unlist(lst[x]))))
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- m1[lower.tri(m1)]
m1
#          Product a Product b Product c
#Product a         0         2         3
#Product b         2         0         3
#Product c         3         3         0
```

Or using `outer`

```
f1 <- function(u, v) length(unique(unlist(c(lst[[u]], lst[[v]]))))
res <- outer(seq_along(lst), seq_along(lst), FUN= Vectorize(f1)) *!diag(3)
dimnames(res) <- rep(list(names(lst)),2)
res
#          Product a Product b Product c
#Product a         0         2         3
#Product b         2         0         3
#Product c         3         3         0
```

For the second case

```
tcrossprod(table(df))*!diag(3)
#            Products
#Products    Product a Product b Product c
# Product a         0         2         1
# Product b         2         0         1
# Product c         1         1         0
```

Comment: If want data with a combination of sets of three products, what would be the best way. So, I want to see the unique users that used product a OR product b. example: Product a+Product b+Product c = 3 Product a+Product b+Product d = 5.

Comment: @prasara Please post that as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks - I posted a new question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092962/product-usage-combination-in-r)

Comment: In your first solution, I made a small change: m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- t(m1)[upper.tri(t(m1))] - this ensured that the upper half is a mirror of the lower.