# Product usage combination in R

Tags: r, list, combinations

I trying to figure out a way to get a list of product combinations with unique users in R. This is a follow up question to [[Generate matrix of unique user-item cross-product combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089205/generate-matrix-of-unique-user-item-cross-product-combinations][1])

```
df <- data.frame(Products=c('Product a', 'Product b', 'Product a', 
                            'Product c', 'Product b', 'Product c', 'Product d'),
                 Users=c('user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user1', 
                         'user2','user3', 'user1'))
```

Output of df is:

```
   Products Users
1 Product a user1
2 Product b user1
3 Product a user2
4 Product c user1
5 Product b user2
6 Product c user3
7 Product d user1
```

The output I am looking for would be all three product combinations:

```
Product a/Product b/Product c - 3
Product a/Product b/Product d - 2
Product b/Product c/Product d - 3
...
```

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want logical-OR treatment as the relation between users and each product set. In other words, you want to count how many unique users have *any* product in the set. Here's one way of doing it:

```
df <- data.frame(Products=c('Product a','Product b','Product a','Product c','Product b','Product c','Product d'),Users=c('user1','user1','user2','user1','user2','user3','user1'));
comb <- combn(unique(df$Products),3);
data.frame(comb=apply(comb,2,function(x) paste(levels(comb)[x],collapse='/')),num=apply(comb,2,function(x) length(unique(df$Users[as.integer(df$Products)%in%x]))));
##                            comb num
## 1 Product a/Product b/Product c   3
## 2 Product a/Product b/Product d   2
## 3 Product a/Product c/Product d   3
## 4 Product b/Product c/Product d   3
```

---

**Edit:** Logical-AND is trickier, since we need to test for the presence of *every* product for *every* user. I think I found a good solution using `aggregate()` and `match()`:

```
data.frame(comb=apply(comb,2,function(x) paste(levels(comb)[x],collapse='/')),num=apply(comb,2,function(x) sum(aggregate(Products~Users,df,function(y) !any(is.na(match(x,as.integer(y)))))$Products)));
##                            comb num
## 1 Product a/Product b/Product c   1
## 2 Product a/Product b/Product d   1
## 3 Product a/Product c/Product d   1
## 4 Product b/Product c/Product d   1
```

Comment: That works. How would i change it if I wanted to get a logical-AND instead of OR.